# Vuex createPersistedState partial persist not working

Tags: vue.js, vuex, persist

Following the persisted-state documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate), I am trying to partially persist the state like so:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {},
    signupLayout: false,
    adminLayout: false,
    sidebarOpen: false,
    homeLayout: false, /* New - 6/01/2021 */
    cloudinary: {
      cloud_name: "*****",
      base_upload_preset: "*****",
      channel_header_upload_preset: "*****",
      profile_image_upload_preset: "*****",
      audio_upload_preset: "*****",
      cover_image_upload_preset: "*****",
    },
    plugins: [createPersistedState({
      paths: ["user", "signupLayout", "adminLayout", "sidebarOpen", "homeLayout"]
    })],
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
    setSignupLayout(state, bool) {
      state.signupLayout = bool;
    },
    setSidebarOpen(state, bool) {
      state.sidebarOpen = bool;
    },
    setAdminLayout(state, bool) {
      state.adminLayout = bool;
    },

    /* New - 6/01/2021 */
    setHomeLayout(state, bool) {
      state.homeLayout = bool;
    },
  },
```

However, when I try to run the code, nothing is being persisted. Can anybody tell me why, and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the plugins property is incorrect. Should be like this.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
    
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vuex-persistedstate` plugin probably doesn't feel like it needs to save your default state, since nothing has changed. Also I don't see any mutations in your vuex store. The persistedstate plugin works on state mutations, so modify your state with a mutation ([vuex docs mutations page](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)), and the plugin should start to work.

Comment: I do have mutations set, but it's still not working. I've edited my OP code so you can see

Comment: Okay... well pop open the console in your browser dev tools and look for errors - anything red. Anything there?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the times where the answer is very easy. Turns out I had the plugins property INSIDE the state property object. I just moved it outside the state property, and everything now works as intended.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {},
    signupLayout: false,
    adminLayout: false,
    sidebarOpen: false,
    homeLayout: false, /* New - 6/01/2021 */
    cloudinary: {
      cloud_name: "*****",
      base_upload_preset: "*****",
      channel_header_upload_preset: "*****",
      profile_image_upload_preset: "*****",
      audio_upload_preset: "*****",
      cover_image_upload_preset: "*****",
    },
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState({
    paths: ['user', 'signupLayout', 'adminLayout', 'sidebarOpen', 'homeLayout']
  })],
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
    setSignupLayout(state, bool) {
      state.signupLayout = bool;
    },
    setSidebarOpen(state, bool) {
      state.sidebarOpen = bool;
    },
    setAdminLayout(state, bool) {
      state.adminLayout = bool;
    },

    /* New - 6/01/2021 */
    setHomeLayout(state, bool) {
      state.homeLayout = bool;
    },
  },
});
```